# Serial Port Performance

Tags: c#, serial-port

I want to communicate with a DSP using RS232, so I use System.IO.SerialPort to achieve this. Everything goes well except the reading performance.

Every 200ms, the port can received a package of 144 bytes. But in the tests, the applications almost skip every other package. I try to print the system time in the console. It amaze me that the code below (when length = 140) take me over 200ms. It let the application can not handle the data in time.

Does anything wrong I do?

Port Property:

BaudRate = 9600

Parity = None

StopBits = One

```
    private byte[] ReadBytesInSpicifiedLength(int length)
    {
        byte[] des = new byte[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            des[i] = (byte)serialPort.ReadByte();
        }

        return des;
    }
```

Comment: Serial ports date from the stone-age.  A traditional choice for the Baudrate is 9600 baud, it can't move data faster than about 1 msec per byte.  The port settings you use are of course not a minor detail that you can leave out of a question like this.

Comment: @Hans: The data rate described is 720 bytes per second, which fits into 9600 baud (960 bytes per second) with some room to spare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a lot of individual I/O calls, which means a lot of kernel transitions.  Those are expensive.  Not being able to reach 720 bytes per second is surprising, but you can make the data handling an order of magnitude faster by doing block reads:

```
private byte[] ReadBytesWithSpecifiedLength(int length)
{
    byte[] des = new byte[length];
    serialPort.BaseStream.Read(des, 0, des.Length);
    return des;
}
```

If you have timeouts enabled, you could get partial reads.  Then you need to do something like:

```
private byte[] ReadBytesWithSpecifiedLength(int length)
{
    byte[] des = new byte[length];
    int recd = 0;
    do {
        int partial = serialPort.BaseStream.Read(des, recd, length - recd);
        if (partial == 0) throw new IOException("Transfer Interrupted");
        recd += partial;
    } while (recd < length);
    return des;
}
```

The nice thing about `BaseStream` is that it also has async support (via `ReadAsync`).  That's what new C# code should be using.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried this and it makes better performance.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Did you ever complete the serial blogging series that you started at Sparx Engineering?  I'm trying to build a working COM port implementation by cobbling together various examples, yours included.  If you had a working example I could use as a go-by, that'd be a real timesaver for me.

Comment: @MattDavis: I didn't get around to writing more articles; our blog software started eating the content and that really demotivated me.  But I have still been answering serial port questions here on SO.  I definitely recommend using async/await and the ReadAsync functions available on the BaseStream property.

Comment: Thanks, @BenVoigt.  Our application focuses on data collection, so I'm familiar with many of the concepts you've described, such as framing, partial messages, etc.  I've written most of the processing logic for our Ethernet-based collectors, but this is my first foray into the serial world.  FWIW, I appreciate the guidance you've provided at the Sparx blog and here on SO.